# Kendo combobox takes time to load and open if datasource has a huge amount of data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have tried using a Kendo Combobox with a datasource having a structure like:

```
{text: "12 Angry Men", value:"1"}
```

and the Kendo Combobox is initialised as:

```
$("#movies").kendoComboBox({
     dataTextField: "text",
     dataValueField: "value",
     dataSource: data,
     height: 100
})
    .closest(".k-widget")
    .attr("id", "movies_wrapper")
;

$("#filter").kendoDropDownList({
    change: filterTypeOnChanged
});
```

It is found that for data of about 40,000 objects the combobox takes a 3 sec delay to load and 6-7 secs of delay to open it each time.

I debugged the native code and found out that it does take some time to handle the animation for so many objects to be shown in the popup.

I therefore tried passing animation as false.

But this still did not reduce the delay.Can someone help solve this problem?

Comment: Check this example in IE, FF and Chrome. You should see improvement of opening time. If so it is browser issue - you are changing visibility of thousands dom elements and there is nothing you can do to improve it. My suggestion: use autocomplete instead of combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue myself with trying to load approx. 20000 items into a combobox.

The way round it is to use server filtering to only pull back a limited number of results. I find 100 is a decent enough number and if the result isn't there then the filter term needs to be a bit more specific to get the eventual correct item.

It obviously means more trips to the server to get the results but I find that is trade off worth taking.

```
  $('#' + fullControlID).kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: 'Text',
        dataValueField: 'Value',
        filter: "contains",
        autoBind: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        minLength: 3,
        change: function (e) {
            $('#' + fullControlID).data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.read();
        },
        dataSource: {
            serverfiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 100,
            transport: {
                read:
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: transportUrl,
                        cache: false,
                        data: {

                            filterText: function () {
                                var filter = $('#' + fullControlID).data("kendoComboBox").input.val();
                                if(filter === '{the place holder text ignore it}')
                                {
                                    filter = '';
                                }

                                return filter; 
                            }    

                        },
                    }
            }
        }


    });
```

above is some code that I use to do this with the appropriate controller/action (using mvc) behind the scenes.

if you need more info then let me know.

Note: (fullcontrolID is the id for the control that is the combobox).

Comment: Yeah, i read about similar such problems of other kendo widgets(rather any widget) and this seems to be a design guideline that loading so much of a huge data(40K to 90K) would certainly take time for the default DOM rendering.

Comment: This seems to be a design guideline,loading huge data(40K-90K)taking time for the default DOM rendering.My questions are-1)Is this true-If i use server side filtering,it would send a server request with the value i entered after 3 letters each time and get back some subset of data and only this subset of data would be the data source for the widget?2)If i open the combobox without typing anything and i also adopt 'pagination on scrolling' will this still lead to the delay if the user goes on scrolling long as the data would be getting huge after each page is scrolled?

Comment: How should i implement such a case?